# Node js swig object display

Tags: node.js, templates, swig-template

```
{% for item in list %}
        <div class="todo_item">
            <span class="hidden_id">{{ item.id }}</span>
            <div class="item_title"> {{item.title}}</div>
            <div class="item_tooltip">date {{item.dateCreated}}</div>
            <div class="item_tooltip">{{ item|json_encode }}</div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

The {{ item|json_encode }} output is :

```
{"_id":"53f82ab44f3254584e970684","username":"k4","title":"kkk3323","__v":0,"dateCreated":"2014-08-23T05:46:28.326Z","status":true}
```

The {{item.dateCreated}} displays [object Object].

And I use {{ item.id }}, not the {{ item._id }} because of the [object Object] output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `{{item.dateCreated}}` is a `Date` object, I'm assuming... which is why it's showing as `[object Object]`. If you want to format it as a date, there's a `date` filter for this exact purpose: http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/filters/#date

Comment: Yes, this is better way to make it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I should use "safe"

Example:

```
<div class="item_tooltip">date {{item.dateCreated | safe}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you create you're own moment.js filter

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
swig = require('gulp-swig'),
moment = require('moment');

gulp.task('swig',function(){
    gulp.src('./src/*.html)
    .pipe(swig({
    setup: function(swig){
     function Moment(date){return moment(date);};
     swig.setFilter('moment',Momemt);
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest'));
 });
```

Comment: I don't use moment.js, and there is build-in filter, why I should use custom?:)